# What is a Marshal in C#?? and where can i find the copy.Marshal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to capture point clouds from the Meta 2 example MetaGetPointClouds and save them in to a PCD file. The code ends like this:

```
private void MarshalMetaPointCloud()
{
    _pointCloud.num_points = _metaPointCloud.num_points;

    int point_cloud_size = 3 * _pointCloud.num_points;

    Marshal.Copy(_metaPointCloud.points,
                  _pointCloud.points,
                  0, point_cloud_size);
}
```

can someone explain me what is Marshal.Copy, where the pointCloud.points are been saved and how to pass them in to a PCD file ?

This is for Unity Engine using META SDK

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods)?

Comment: Marshal is a class from .NET and copy is a static method from it. It is used to access data stored in unmanaged side (native plugin) from the managed side (your Unity app in C#).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the related documentation

## Marshall class

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshall Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal) documentation.

> Provides a collection of methods for allocating unmanaged memory, copying unmanaged memory blocks, and converting managed to unmanaged types, as well as other miscellaneous methods used when interacting with unmanaged code.

## Copy method

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy)

> Copies data from a managed array to an unmanaged memory pointer, or from an unmanaged memory pointer to a managed array.

Comment: thank you , but could you tell me where i can find this marshal copy?

Comment: Bernard, I'm not sure this should be answered.

Comment: i know that is a noob question , but i am really confused thats why i am asking . Thank you for your help .

Comment: The Marshall class is part of the .NET Framework, and also available in .NET Core.